# Converting eps to jpg with Imagemagick creating 0KB file in .net 4.5 WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, imagemagick

We are creating a REST service that will return a stream of an image in a given dimension. We are requesting the image name and the final type and max dimension. We call `ImageMagick` process that creates the resized image. We can successfully create the image in a 4.0 asp.net application, or a 3.5 WCF service. However, when we try to call either of these from the 4.5 REST WCF service, the image created by `ImageMagick` is a 0KB file. I have tried setting permissions but it did not seem to work. I need help in resolving this issue.

Comment: I'm afraid you didn't provide enough details for us to answer this - we can only guess at the possible causes. You'll need to debug this further, and get back with more details (and if possible: relevant code to reproduce this issue).

Comment: I am WCF team. We need more information to diagnose this issue. Can I ask you a few clarifying questions. (1) Is your WCF 4.5 REST application calling 4.0 asp net app or ImageMagick application (2) Can you share the code for this REST service method and any relevant pieces of code with us? (3) When you say "is 0KB file" do you mean the file generated by ImageMagick.exe is 0KB or the file received on making the REST call is 0KB.

Comment: We are unable to reproduce the issue at our end. Please contact us on netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com if this still reproduces for you.